# Where are my DataModel classes after added ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok after finally getting the correct connection string to create the Mdf file in the App_Data folder. I tried to add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the Models folder following the tutorial in ["Beginnning ASP.NET MVC 4"](http://www.apress.com/9781430257523).
However once added I should have being able to expand the DataModel.edmx to show the model classes, all thats showing is the DataModel.Designer.cs .
Has anyone come across this before ?
Also should I also be seeing this database in my SQL Express ?
Visual studio 2010, windows xp machie
Original Connection string, in case it helps...

```
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HaveYouSeenMe;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HaveYouSeenMe.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Connection string added when created ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

```
 <add name="EntitiesConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\HaveYouSeenMe.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

open your EDMX and in Properties Window change `Code generation strategy to Default` and save your EDMX file

[image]

**Update**

Check out following link for more details

[Database First Approach in Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/database-first-approach-in-entity-framework/)

Comment: should I have the two connection strings ?

Comment: still nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: check the link provided in answer.

Comment: OK I'll check it out, last question based on original connection string should the database have created in SQL Express aswell ?

Comment: @mkell:Yes defualt connectionstring create database in sqlexpress

Comment: Thats part of the problem then , the database was not created in SQL. Any idea why ?

Comment: I hit a problem at test Connection - it's saying the a database with the same name already exist's when I navigate to the mdf file. But I'm not seeing it in SQL, I did try detaching a db of the same name earlier, but can't locate it to fully delete !!

Comment: I think  database created in App_Data folder.Click on show all files in visual studio

Comment: Yes it's present there, but is the problem not that SQL Express has a detached db of the same name, if I find it and manage to delete it, will that solve the issue ?

Comment: You should be able to select SQL Server Database File, then change the connection string to connect to SqlExpress

Comment: Selecting SQL Server Database File, resulted in the same thing edmx but no classes, what should my connection string now look like to connect to SQLExpress ?